# Display posts in 3 days chunk

Tags: wp-query

I want to display posts from the past 3 days, ordered by `meta_value_num`. Then when you reach the final page, I want to loop through another 3 days and show those posts. So navigation never ends, the user can browse through every published post...

How can I do this? My [WP_Query()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) arguments are:

```
$args = array(
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => 5,
    'paged' => $paged,
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'meta_key' => '__votes',
    'date_query' => array(
        array(
            'after' => '3 days ago'
        )
    )
);
```

That shows posts from last 3 days.

Comment: And what will happen when pagination ends ? Pagination will be appended with new page links ?

Answer (score 1):

It may be that you could use some sort of lazy loading plugin. This could be done in a custom way using admin_ajax and adding user events but there are a number of plugins available that may be able to help out.

This plugin - https://wordpress.org/plugins/ajax-load-more/ - allows for the implementation of the lazy loading of posts and may be what you require.